# Off screen div is giving body a horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar on the right that'll pop out from off-screen once triggered.  I keep it in the `body` tag because it needs to always be the same height as the entire page which varies from page-to-page.  If I give the `body` an `overflow-x: hidden`, it'll hide the contents on smaller browser windows and not allow them to scroll.  Is there any way around this?

I need the sidebar to scroll with the page, so I can't use `position: fixed`

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

This is just a stripped down example.

Comment: Please post JSFiddle link so we can see it visually.

Comment: @wazaaaap my apologies, as soon as you posted that, I updated it with some example code.  super basic stuff.

Comment: @misterManSam the contents of the sidebar need to scroll w the page.  this keeps it stationary.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?  Your example has no content.   What is the DESIRED behavior?  We can't read your mind.  When is the DIV displayed?

Comment: @Lance it's way too much code to post on here not to mention part of my company's website, so i posted a stripped version of the basic concept.  it's supposed to pop out from the right side, off the page, when triggered.  the desired behavior is to not give the page a horizontal scrollbar.  the div is displayed when triggered (from clicking a button).  this is all in the body of my question.  it's just a basic sidebar that spans 100% height of the page, hides offscreen, and pops out when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple answer is to place the sidebar inside a `position: absolute` container (`.hideScroll`)  which has `overflow: hidden`.

The new parent is given the entire width and height of the viewport and wont affect body scrolling.

In this example I have used [viewport percentage lengths (vh)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) instead of percentage heights. These units get their height from the viewport and are not relative to any parents.

### Example

Hover over the body in the window to trigger the sidebar.

```css
.hideScroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #F00;
  right: -100px;
  transition: right 1s;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  /*150 height is for the example to make the body scroll*/
  height: 150vh;
}
/*For example to show the sidebar on body hover*/

body:hover #sidebar {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hideScroll">
  <div id="sidebar">Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add display: none; to the sidebar:

```
#sidebar { display: none; position: absolute; top: 0; right: -100px; width: 100px; height: 100%; }
```

Then when you move it into the main window, set display: block; at the same time.

Comment: then i lose the scrolling animation.  and if i have it display before the animation, it'll give me the sidebar which i don't think is very clean.

Comment: Well, you don't mention anything about an animation.  If you show more of your code we can provide better help.